# Yii2 failed create new project with composer

Tags: php, yii

my php version is 5.4.6 and after downloading last snapshot of composer i can't create new project and upadate composer version.

**php composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic**

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                      
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto  
  failed to open stream: operation failed                                                       



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

**php composer.phar self-update**

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                      
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto  
  failed to open stream: operation failed                                                       

self-update
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yii2 Installation**

---

***(1) First install Composer (LINUX):***

***Locally:***

*curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php*

*php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php*

*curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin*

**OR**

***Globally:***

*curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php*

*mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer*

***(1) First install Composer (WINDOWS):***

*C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin*

*C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php*

**Note:** If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini

*C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat*

*C:\Users\username>composer -V*
Composer version 27d8904

---

***(2) Yii2 framework online downloads:***

***Basic App:***
*php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta*

***Advanced App:***
*php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-beta*

---

***(3) Other App Settings Command:***

*php init*

**Note:** set DB Cofig common/config/local-main.php

*php yii migrate*

---

***Refference:***

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-start-installation.html

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/apps/advanced